# Can I update the auto pause delay on a SQL Azure database using T-SQL?

Tags: t-sql, azure-sql-database

Does anyone know a way of updating the auto-pause details for a SQL Azure Serverless database using T-SQL? We have a process that deploys new databases from a database copy command, and we would like to set the auto-pause delay (including the ability to turn it off) using T-SQL.

I have scoured the documentation, and I can find a reference for doing this via the Azure CLI, however our pipeline is built using T-SQL.

I'm currently using the following T-SQL to create a copy of the database:

```
CREATE DATABASE "TemplateDb" 
    AS COPY OF "NewDb" (SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = 'GP_S_Gen5_2');
```

Answer (score 0):

When using T-SQL to create or alter a serverless database, default values are applied for the min vcores and auto-pause delay.

The min vcores and auto-pause delay default values:

**Min vCores:** 0.5 vCores

**Autopause delay:**    60 minutes

> These default values can later be changed from the portal or via other management APIs (PowerShell, Azure CLI, REST API).

Reference: [Using T-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/serverless-tier-overview#use-transact-sql-t-sql-1)

Comment: Thanks.  I was really trying to do this through T-SQL if possible.  Users who deploy databases via this function will not have access to the portal or powershell so we wanted to bake it in to the workflow.  The Rest API might work though.